# Ehcache Default values

Tags: ehcache

I am using ehcache in my project and am facing some performance issue. Few question which exact answer I am not able to find on internet.

1. If sizeOfPolicy is not defined in ehcache.xml file- Is there any default value of this.
2. If writeToDisk is true and maxElementInDisk is not defined - Is there any limit on writing to disk then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the decompiled sources for Ehcache 2.6:

1. The default sizeOfPolicy is maxDepth=1000 and maxDepthExceededBehavior="continue".
2. The default value of maxElementsOnDisk is 0, which translates to no limit. Hope you have a lot of disk space! :)

Comment: http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd as per this resource we don't have default value to maxDepth

Comment: <xs:element name="sizeOfPolicy">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="maxDepth" use="required" type="xs:integer" />
<xs:attribute name="maxDepthExceededBehavior" use="optional" default="continue" type="maxDepthExceededBehavior" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

Comment: Could you please explain me above meaning of xml

Comment: There is no default defined in the schema but if you look at the class that the SizeOfPolicy portion of ehcache.xml is parsed into (SizeOfPolicyConfiguration), it has a constant field DEFAULT_MAX_SIZEOF_DEPTH, which is set to 1000.